# Calculating Yaw from Relative position of 2 accelerometers

Tags: accelerometer, imu, drone

First of all, apologies for the length.

I'm building a drone and have come across the issue of a 6 degree IMU being unable to calculate a sufficiently stable yaw number on it's own. The normal solution for this would be to incorporate some variety of data from a magnetometer, but I was wondering if it would be possible to do it via the relative positioning of 2 IMUs? If we consider the below very poorly drawn fix wing drone:

[image]

The green IMU is the ‘master’ IMU while the pink one is the ‘slave’. The green IMU is located in the exact center of the aircraft while the pink one is located some fixed distance (r) along the 0 degree bearing from the green IMU.

Lets just consider the yaw angle here (no pitch or roll movement) for simplicity in the calculation.

We can calculate the distance moved in the x and y directions during a timestep by integrating the accelerometer values as follows:

*movement = (initial_velocity * timestep) + 0.5 (accel_val * sqr(timestep))*

*initial_v = initial_velocity + accel_val * timestep*

After doing that in both directions for  both x and y for both IMUs we should have 2 vectors of x and y movement distances – one for each IMU.

To get a ‘movement due to rotation’ vector it’s simply:

*rotation_movement_vec =  secondary_movement_vec – primary_movement_vec*

We can then use the values from this vector with trigonometry to calculate our yaw delta for the timestep:

*yaw_delta = 90 – arcsin(rotation_movement_vec-y / r)*

And total yaw is obviously just a running sum of the yaw deltas:

*yaw = yaw + yaw_delta*

Is there any reason this wouldn’t work/be correct?